# Piecewise integration fail or something else?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, piecewise

I have a not-so-complicated piecewise cubic function, shown below as the yellow curve on the right. It's derivative is on the left; the blue lines are references. Please see the code below where I call it **myF** (and its derivative myf).

To my surprise, the integration with a parameter $u$ and sine in the argument gives an ugly result involving the complex $i$.

> Is the result of $\int$myF$(u\sin x)$d$x$ (as shown in the screenshot below) correct? Or is it some kind of failure due to my erroneous way of using `Integrate` coupled with`Piecewise`?

As just the area under the curve modulated by sine, I for now don't see how this can be mathematically true to have involved $\sqrt{-1}$.

[image]

Screen shot below:

[image]

The code to define the curves, generate the plots, and do the integration is below. When the parameter $u < \frac12$ of course there's no problem since the integration doesn't go over the `splitting point' (where is differentiable).

I tried various ways to code the integration with assumptions, but the outcomes are basically the same. Some hint or confirmation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
ClearAll[myF, myf, u, v, ImgSz];
myF[v_] := Piecewise[{
    {0, v < 0},
    {4/3 v^3, 0 <= v < 1/2},
    {1/3 (1 - 6 v + 12 v^2 - 4 v^3), 1/2 <= v < 1},
    {1, v >= 1}
    }];
myf = D[myF[u], u] /. {u -> v};
ImgSz = 250;
Row[{  Plot[{ 1,  (*  symmetry reference  *)
    myf
    }, {v, -.3, 1.3}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, 2}, ImageSize -> ImgSz],
  Plot[{ v, (*  linear reference  *)
    myF[v]
    }, {v, -.3, 1.3}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1}, ImageSize -> ImgSz]
  }]
Assuming[  1/2 < u < 1 ,
 Integrate[ myF[ u Sin[x]], {x, 0, Pi}] ]
```

---

**Summarizing Edit**

Okay, so I couldn't recognize the expression as real-disguised-in-complex-conjugate, neither did I know reliable ways to test that. I'm glad to have learned from both answer posts.

In my case, defining the function with `UnitStep` doesn't allow Mathematica to evaluate differently like in another post (which I cannot find right now). Nor does `PrincipalValue -> True` or change of variables apply here as [it does sometimes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127301). I have accepted that in my case I need to post-process the expression the way I see fit. Nonetheless, for the record, there are some known bugs, old and [new](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99395), [solved](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48437) and [unsolved](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127448).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the answer to a real-looking expression as follows:

```
FullSimplify[
 ComplexExpand[answer, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}],
 1/2 < u < 1]
(*
  1/9 (-11 Sqrt[-1 + 4 u^2] + 16 u^2 (u - Sqrt[-1 + 4 u^2]) + 6 (1 + 6 u^2) ArcSec[2 u])
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just because an expression contains the imaginary unit $i$ doesn't mean that its imaginary part is non-zero. For example, you could naïvely think that
$$
\frac{1}{x-i}+\frac{1}{x+i}
$$
is complex, but actually it equals $\frac{2 x}{x^2+1}$, which is explicitly real (for real $x$).

In your particular case, you found an expression that looks complex, but it is actually real. For example, if you set `u=3/4` and evaluate the integral numerically, you get `0.718597+i5.5511e-17`, which has an spurious imaginary part due to numerical error.

If you evaluate

```
Plot[ReIm@NIntegrate[myF[u Sin[x]], {x, 0, Pi}], {u, 1/2, 1}]
```

you get

[image]

which confirms the fact that the integral is indeed real - its imaginary part vanishes.